# How to remove a users manager in AzureAD using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

I'm using the [Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) (Version 2.1.0) to write an app for Azure AD user management. I'm able to set the Manager of a user but have no idea how to clear the field.

Unfortunately the sample project provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) do not contain this function either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to clear the "manager" field using the code below. It is not using the Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient library but gets the job done.

```
var token = <get your adal token here>
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var url = "https://graph.windows.net/<tenant domain>/users/<userid>/$links/manager?api-version=1.6"
var resp = httpClient.DeleteAsync(url).Result;
if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // log / throw exception etc.   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform a `DELETE` HTTP request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_email>/manager/$ref` (make sure to replace the `<user_email>` in the URL.

A successful call will receive `204` response code and empty string as the response body.

This method is currently missing from the Microsoft Graph API docs but should be added in the future. (see [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5807))

Also you should start using Microsoft Graph (`graph.microsoft.com`) instead of Azure AD Graph (`graph.windows.net`) as the latter is becoming obsolete. (See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/))

Answer (score -2):

```
//Assign and remove user's manager
// User.Manager = newUser as DirectoryObject;
           User.Manager = null;
```

Comment: When I try to set the Manager Property of a loaded User (casted to DirectoryObject) to null as you suggest and call target.UpdateAsync() afterwards, the manager is still there when I reload the object.